# Ecma 5.1 and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-5

Is there a direct relation between these two? Is it necessary to use ECMA 5.1 scripting languages (javascript) in HTML5 pages.

Thanks

Comment: This may be of help: http://www.lesliesikos.com/what-are-the-differences-between-html5-and-html-5-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

`HTML5` is markup used to structure your elements and `ECMA` is a family of languages used to manipulate it (and perform some other tasks).

If you want all (most anyway) browsers to be able to understand your code, then keeping to [ECMA 5.1 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) my be a good idea. However, `HTML 5` doesn't require you, as a standard, to use any scripting language. In fact `HTML 5` is not concerned with anything other than... well HTML.

Comment: yes this is what I wanted to know... I know you are not "required" to use any scripting at all in HTML5, but I wanted to know if I use one, according to standards, has it to be ECMA 5.1 compliant? I guess no is the answer... these version postfixes 5 confused me a little :-)

Comment: It sounds a bit like the primary task of ECMAScript is to manipulate HTML, which is not the case. ECMAScript as such is not related to HTML or DOM at all. The browsers provide the DOM API.

Comment: @user503510: No, it's not related at all (seen from the specification). HTML, or lets the say the HTML-DOM extension(s) is (are) just a definition of interfaces which have to be implemented.

Comment: @FelixKling: You are right `ECMA` in general is a powerful tool which extends way beyond `DOM` manipulation. However most of the jobs done by ECMA-family languages (in web development) comes down to manipulating DOM tree and performing simple calculations to aid this.

Comment: Felix, I thought the main purpose of web scripting languages was to enable the interactivity in web pages, and that would be basically to be able to manipulate html... isnt it? Thanks...

Comment: @user503510: Although JavaScript (ECMAScript) was born as a web scripting language, it's just another programming language. If browsers would support Python, we could also write all our web scripts in Python. It's only the combination of language (ECMAScript) + APIs (DOM) (provided by the environment, the browser) which makes it work together. Each piece is independent though.

Comment: @user503510 `ECMAScript` is widely used on websites but it's not the only (or main) job it does. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) to see how many different application it has - event `ANT` and `KDE` use it.